# Чем определяется цена на доменные зоны?

Tags: веб-программирование

Так просто интересно стало. Убивает разница между .ru и .ua в 15-20 раза:)

Comment: спросом и предложением.

Comment: @KoVadim, не совсем. Можно сюда добавить и "степень жадности". Не думаю, что в России спрос на доменную зону **ru** меньше, чем в Украине на доменную зону **ua**. Однако, в России стоимость **ru** в год приблизительно 20 баксов, а в Украине **ua** - 50.

Comment: степень жадности не имеет значения. Если стоимость будет большой - покупать будут меньше. Поэтому цену уменьшают/увеличивают, но ровно до тех пор, пока прибыль не станет максимальной. 

Может просто в Украине могут платить 50 долларов, а в России нет?:)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню (поправьте, если не прав) регистрация ru-домена доступна и физ. и юр. лицам, и не требует документального подтверждения.

Регистрация .ua домена же возможна только на основе свидетельства на торговую марку.

В .EU требуется документ резидента физ или юрлица. В .ltd.uk требуется регистраци юрлица и т.п.

Эти доменых зоны более высоко котируются поисковиками. В этих доменых зонах практически исключен срач и г-но-сайты. Ну и в целом легкий налет элитарности)))

Стоит ли за это платить порядка полсотни баксов в месяц? Однозначно - да.

Comment: Насчет цен... Тут разница между разными регистраторами чуть ли не до двух раз бывает доходит (на одинаковые домены)... Банальная коньюктура по-моему.